# Make small pandas dataframes based on combinations of values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

Lets say I have a dataframe below.

```
A   B
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   1
b   2
b   3
c   1
c   2
c   3
d   1
```

I want to create dataframes with two columns: A : unique values in columns A and B: Possible values in column B for a given unique value in A. Note that all these dataframes must be unique. Example of few possible dataframes are given in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Just sort the dataframe by columns A, then slice it base on the length of you data using loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to group the values by column A, collecting values in B in lists, create a cartesian product of all these lists, and format back into a dataframe

First we load the data and `groupby` by column A, collecting all values in `B` into lists:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data = StringIO('''
A   B
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   1
b   2
b   3
c   1
c   2
c   3
d   1
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+')
df2 = df.groupby('A').agg(list)
df2
```

`df2` looks like this:

```
    B
A   
a   [1, 2, 3]
b   [1, 2, 3]
c   [1, 2, 3]
d   [1]
```

next we extract all lists in column B into a list of lists:

```
all_lists = df2['B'].to_list()
all_lists
```

it looks like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1]]
```

Now the main step, create a product of the lists using `MultiIndex.from_product` functionality

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(all_lists)
mi
```

`mi` looks like this:

```
MultiIndex([(1, 1, 1, 1),
            (1, 1, 2, 1),
            (1, 1, 3, 1),
            (1, 2, 1, 1),
            (1, 2, 2, 1),
            (1, 2, 3, 1),
            (1, 3, 1, 1),
            (1, 3, 2, 1),
            (1, 3, 3, 1),
            (2, 1, 1, 1),
            (2, 1, 2, 1),
            (2, 1, 3, 1),
            (2, 2, 1, 1),
            (2, 2, 2, 1),
            (2, 2, 3, 1),
            (2, 3, 1, 1),
            (2, 3, 2, 1),
            (2, 3, 3, 1),
            (3, 1, 1, 1),
            (3, 1, 2, 1),
            (3, 1, 3, 1),
            (3, 2, 1, 1),
            (3, 2, 2, 1),
            (3, 2, 3, 1),
            (3, 3, 1, 1),
            (3, 3, 2, 1),
            (3, 3, 3, 1)],
           )
```

we are almost there -- now convert into a df and make sure we have the right label. Also remove duplicates (none in this case but in general a good idea)

```
(pd.DataFrame(index = mi)
    .reset_index()
    .drop_duplicates()
    .set_axis(df2.index, axis=1) 
    .T
)
```

and we get a dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
A                                                                                   
a   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   ... 2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
b   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   1   ... 3   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3
c   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   ... 3   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
d   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   ... 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

where the index is the old column A and each column is a unique combination of relevant values from old column B

You can split it into separate dataframes if you need to, by looping over columns if you wish